# Best Practices: Create several variables for one-time use or call the result of a function inside other functions?

Tags: python, optimization

I have several functions. The first two return a `dict` from the contents of two files, the third one compares and merges the first two, returning a third `dict`, and the last one generates an file from the third `dict`.

Have two ways of doing it:

```
var1 = func1(file1)
var2 = func2(file2)
var3 = func3(var1, var2)
fun4(var3)
```

This will generate the file, but will copy the results of the functions several times, slowing the program a bit and using more resources.

The other way is:

```
func4(func3(func1(file1), func2(file2)))
```

This will generate the same output, but seems a bit more difficult to read, although I have determined it is a bit faster than assigning variables.

Which is the best way to do this in terms of design and best practices? Is there any better alternative to accomplish the objective described?

Thanks.

Comment: Copying a single reference is very lightweight.  Yes, the second will be marginally faster, but the difference will be nearly undetectable.

Comment: Thank you very much, @TomKarzes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good question for the StackOverflow format, as this is a bit of a matter of opinion.

However, in my experience (and in a lot of other programmers minds as well, read [here](https://wiki.c2.com/?OptimizeLater) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)), **readability >> pre-optimization**.

Finish writing your software while maximizing testability, readability, maintainability, **traceability**, and sanity (all of which are better in the first option you suggested). Then, if it's slow, use a profiler to understand why. It will probably won't be the lines you pre-optimized anyway ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how python variables work. In python everything is a reference. Nothing gets copied unless you explicitly copy it. SO essentially

```
func4(func3(func1(file1), func2(file2)))
```

is the same as:

```
var1 = func1(file1)
var2 = func2(file2)
var3 = func3(var1, var2)
fun4(var3)
```

Aside from that, you can experiment with pipelines.